# iOS Cordova 3.x: Device plugin

Tags: ios, cordova

I am testing out the device plugin for a Cordova 3.3 project on iOS Simulator 6.0 7.0

So my steps:

1. npm install cordova
2. cordova create MyFunkyApp
3. cd MyFunkyApp
4. cordova platform add ios
5. cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
6. change index.html to

> Device Properties Example
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
>
> // Wait for device API libraries to load
> //
> document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
>
> // device APIs are available
> //
> function onDeviceReady() {
>     var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
>     element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' +
>                         'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
>                         'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
>                         'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
>                         'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
>                         'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
> }
>
> </script>   </head>   <body>
> <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>   </body> </html>
> ```

This script from cordova.apache.org Device API

But its not works. Loading device properties... all the time on screen. What I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to command-line build your project first, as opposed to just building it with Xcode:

```
cordova build ios
```

Then run it in the simulator - should work.